# How to do repeated sequence check

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

Question: Repeated Sequence Check
The program should enter a string (possibly containing blanks), and determine whether the characters are in
lexicographic order.
For example:

- “12AABab” is in order since each character is less than or equal to the one following it (‘1’ < ‘2’, ‘2’ <
  ‘A’, ‘B’ < ‘a’, etc.) according to the Unicode character sequence.
- “abCDef” is out of order, because ‘b’ > ‘C’ (lower-case letters come after upper-case letters in the
  Unicode sequence).

If the string is in order, the program should display “The input is in order”; otherwise, it should display
“The input is out of order”
The program should repeat this process until the user enters the string “quit”, regardless of case. It should
not check the sequence of “quit”.
Finally, the program should display “Goodbye”.

Notes:

- This program will require nested loops. The inner loop will check the sequence of the input, while
  the outer loop will repeat the input and check process.
- Be sure to reinitialize all variables at the start of the outer loop.
- A string of length 0 or 1 is considered to be in order by definition.

what I could do best is: (I tried with 2 other different methods I could send it too if you like)

```
package homelab03;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Quest3deneme3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String whole,remain,d,e;
        char h1,h2;
        int lenght,b,c,sayac;
        //int[] a;
        String[] a;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an input string:");
        whole = keyboard.nextLine();
        whole=whole.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        lenght=(int)whole.length();
        //System.out.println(+lenght);
        remain=whole;
        sayac=0;
        c=0;
        b=0;
        a= new String[lenght];

        //boolean cem = d.compareTo(e);
        while(b<lenght)
        {
            a[b]=remain.substring(b,b+1);
            remain=remain.substring(b+1);
            System.out.println(a[b]);
            d=a[b];
            e=a[c];
            while(a[b]<a[c] )
            {
            sayac=sayac+1;
            h1=h2;
        }
        }   
            if(sayac==lenght)
            {
                System.out.println("oley");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("nooo");
            }
    }
    //a[b]=remain.substring(b,b+1);
    //remain=whole.substring(b+1);
    //System.out.println(a[b]);
}
```

note we haven't learned a[b] <= this thing yet but I find it online if the solution won't require that that would be better.

note 2: we haven't learned regex either I think that might be dissalowed (I found some answers with that online but I think I won't get credit for that)

Comment: Easiest solution would probably be using a `for` loop with [`String.charAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) to compare each character with the one following it.

Comment: I can't see any question, just a homework task...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check this code. Maybe it will inspire you :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class howToDoRepeatedSequanceCheck {

  public void repeatedTests() {

      String whole;
      int inputLength,i;

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter an input string:");
      whole = keyboard.nextLine();

      while(!whole.equals("quit")) {

        whole=whole.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        inputLength = whole.length();
        boolean isInOrder = true;
        i = 0;
        while(isInOrder && i<inputLength-1 ) {
          if(whole.charAt(i)<whole.charAt(i+1)) {
//            System.out.println("ok " + whole.charAt(i)+ " < " +whole.charAt(i+1));
          }else {
//            System.out.println("error");
            isInOrder = false;
          }
          i++;
        }

        if(isInOrder == true) {
          System.out.println("The input is in order");
        }else {
          System.out.println("The input is out of order");
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Enter an input string:");
        whole = keyboard.nextLine();
      }
      System.out.println("Goodbye");

  }

}
```